# C#. Как привести результат работы generic функции к типу T?

Tags: c#

Есть функция выполняет математические действия над переменной разных типов, не могу понять как преобразовать результат выполнения к типу T?

```
private T ApplyMath<T>(T data)
{
    return data switch
    {
        int intVal => intVal + 10,
        DateTime dateTimeVal => dateTimeVal.AddMinutes(1.0),
        _ => data
    };
}
```

Явное приведение к T не работает.

```
(T)(intVal + 10)
```

Comment: Попробуйте через object.

Comment: Что значит "не работает", в чём это выражается?

Comment: int intVal => (T)(object)(intVal + 10), так работает, но у меня ValueObject все входные переменные будет boxing/unboxing. Лучше так не делать?

Comment: Лучше просто перегрузить функцию

Comment: Не работает значит не компилируется
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'T'

Comment: Насчет перегрузки думал, просто контекс использования тоже generic

Comment: public string CalcFinishValue<T>(T data)
        {
            var afterMath = ApplyMath(data);
            var formatVal = ConvertByFormat(data);
            return StartMiddleWarePipline(formatVal);
        }